# HashMap with search.h

Tags: c, xml, search, hashmap

I have a xml file with coordinates (lon, lat) and an id. The problem is I want to store these informations in a `HashMap` but I don't know the size max of my file. I saw some example in internet:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <search.h> // hcreate_r() hdestroy_r() struct hsearch_data
#include <string.h> // memset()
#include <stdio.h>  // perror()
#include <stdlib.h> //exit()

#define TAB 4

...

struct hsearch_data hash;
size_t max_element = 42; // of elements in search table

...

char *food[] = { "Apple",
                 "Banana",
                 "Lemon",
                 "Carrot"
};
char *color[] = { "red",
                  "yellow",
                  "yellow",
                  "orange"
};

// we create the hash
memset(&hash, 0, sizeof(hash));
if (hcreate_r(max_element, &hash) == 0) {
    perror("hcreate_r");
    exit(1);
}

/*
  adding some elements
*/

// we destroy the hash
hdestroy_r(&hash);
```

`max_element` isn't know in my case and I don't know how to fix that, here my code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>

#define MAX_REF_LEN 10

static char der_ref[MAX_REF_LEN + 1];
static xmlChar *der_intitule = NULL;

void debut_document(void *user_data) {
    *der_ref = '\0';
    der_intitule = NULL;
}

void debut_element(void *user_data, const xmlChar *name, const xmlChar **attrs) {
    if (xmlStrEqual(name, BAD_CAST "node")) {
        if (NULL != attrs) {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; attrs[i] != NULL; i += 2) {
                if (xmlStrEqual(attrs[i], BAD_CAST "lat")) {
                    strncpy(der_ref, (char *)attrs[i + 1], MAX_REF_LEN);
                    printf("lat %s\n", der_ref);
                } else
                if (xmlStrEqual(attrs[i], BAD_CAST "lon")) {
                    strncpy(der_ref, (char *)attrs[i + 1], MAX_REF_LEN);
                    printf("lon %s\n", der_ref);
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}

int main() {

    xmlSAXHandler sh = { 0 };

    sh.startDocument = debut_document;
    sh.startElement = debut_element;

    if (xmlSAXUserParseFile(&sh, NULL, "map.osm") != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Une erreur est survenue lors du parsing\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I didn't implement the search library yet but I want to create my HashMap in my `debut_element` function.

"map.osm" is my xml file but the size is not fix.

Comment: [`hsearch`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/hsearch_r) is a very restricted hash table implementation: It has a fixed maximum size and it doesn't allow to delete keys. You might be better off with another, more versatile hash table implementation. (Or you could roll your own, it isn't that hard.)

Comment: It's not clear from your problem description what your key for the hash map is. If you want to look up nodes by coordinates, a kd-tree or other spatial representation might be better.

Comment: key : id 
value : (lon, lat) 
Exemple of node :<node id="365929703" visible="true" version="6" changeset="27812151" timestamp="2014-12-30T23:25:24Z" user="Mikhail Kotelnikov" uid="1789303" lat="48.8310657" lon="2.3810055"/> we use here id, lat and lon the rest of the node is useless for my program. Can I use a couple as a value in search ?

Comment: _Can I use a couple as a value in search?_ You mean whether you can use (lat, lon) as key? In principle, you can use any well-defined data structure as key with the right hash function. I don't recommend to use the floating-point positions as keys, though, because close values will have very differnt hashes. Paris is on (48.9067, 2.3508), but (48.01, 2.35) should probably also map to Paris. A spatial representation is better here.

Comment: Well, I can use the key value as a char * :
The <search.h> header shall define the ENTRY type for structure entry which shall include the following members:

char    *key
void    *data 

So I have no choice my key value must be a char * but I can convert it with atol I suppose.

Comment: Yes, but you will have to store the id as string somewhere, too. I really recommend to write your own hash table which uses an int as key.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow, should I do a struct with key : int and value : long ** ?

Answer (score 0):

The hash table implementation in `<search.h>` has several restrictions: You must know the size beforehand and you can't remove items.

In your case, you can still use it, provided that your list of elements doesn't change after you read it. Read all items into a danymic array first. After all locations have been read, create the hash table with the desired dimension and add all locations.

The values are pointers to the items in the array, the key must be a string. Therefore, you should keep a string representation of the id with the location.

Here's an example implementation. Instead of reading the locations from the file, it creates some random values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <search.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

struct loc {
    int id;
    char label[12];
    double lat, lon;
};

struct map {
    size_t size;
    size_t count;
    struct loc *loc;
    struct hsearch_data hash;
};

double urand(void)
{
    return rand() / (1.0 + RAND_MAX);
}

void loc_print(struct loc *loc)
{
    printf("%s: (%g%c, %g%c)\n", loc->label,
        fabs(loc->lon), loc->lon > 0 ? 'E' : 'W',
        fabs(loc->lat), loc->lat > 0 ? 'N' : 'S');
}

void map_destroy(struct map *map)
{
    free(map->loc);
    hdestroy_r(&map->hash);
    free(map);
}

struct map *map_create(void)
{
    struct map *map = calloc(1, sizeof(*map));
    size_t i;

    while (0.005 * map->count < urand()) {
        struct loc *p;

        if (map->count == map->size) {
            map->size *= 2;
            if (map->size == 0) map->size = 1024;

            p = realloc(map->loc, map->size * sizeof(*p));
            if (p == NULL) {
                map_destroy(map);
                exit(1);
            }
            map->loc = p;
        }

        p = &map->loc[map->count];
        p->lon = 360.0 * urand() - 180.0;
        p->lat = 180.0 * urand() - 90.0;
        p->id = map->count + 1;
        snprintf(p->label, sizeof(p->label), "%d", p->id);
        map->count++;

        loc_print(p);
    }

    hcreate_r(3 * map->count / 2, &map->hash);

    for (i = 0; i < map->count; i++) {
        struct loc *p = &map->loc[i];        
        ENTRY e, *res = NULL;

        e.key = p->label;
        e.data = p;
        hsearch_r(e, ENTER, &res, &map->hash);
    }

    return map;
}

struct loc *map_find(struct map *map, int id)
{
    char label[12];
    ENTRY e, *res;

    snprintf(label, sizeof(label), "%d", id);
    e.key = label;
    hsearch_r(e, FIND, &res, &map->hash);

    if (res) return res->data;
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    struct map *map;
    int i;

    srand(time(NULL));

    puts("Creating map");
    map = map_create();

    puts("Looking up values");
    for (i = 5; i < 80; i += 5) {
        struct loc *loc = map_find(map, i);

        if (loc) {
            loc_print(loc);
        } else {
            printf("%d not found.\n", i);
        }
    }

    map_destroy(map);

    return 0;
}
```

You can even use this technique when your list of locations gows later on: Just destroy the old hash table if a certain threshold, say 75% of the hash table size, is reached and create it new with a larger size. This should work, because the hash table is just an auxiliary representation of existing data that enable fast lookup.